# Controlled ThreadPoolExecutor in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I need to create a global ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in my Spring application which will be responsible for running multi-threaded tasks in my application.

However, for every request I want to limit the number of threads used from that global ThreadPool. How should I ensure that this restriction, per request, is enforced?

For eg.

I create a global thread-pool with max pool size as 50 threads. But I want to limit the number of threads per Request to say 5 threads. But these 5 threads could only be allocated from the 50 threads available in global thread pool defined in Configuration file.

Configuration class for creating the task executor.

```
@Configuration
public class ThreadPoolConfiguration {

    @Value("${threadpool.corepoolsize}")
    int corePoolSize;

    @Value("${threadpool.maxpoolsize}")
    int maxPoolSize;

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        pool.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        pool.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return pool;
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPool;

    @RequestMapping("/process")
    public String process(){

        String msg = "";
        List<Future<String>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int threadNumber = 0; threadNumber < 5; threadNumber ++){
            CallableWorker callableTask = new CallableWorker(String.valueOf(threadNumber));
            Future<String> result = threadPool.submit(callableTask);
            futureList.add(result);
        }

        for(Future<String> future: futureList){
            try {
                msg += future.get() + "#####";
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }

        return msg;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: This is just sample code I got from a [blog post](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-core/spring-threadpooltaskexecutor-callable-interface-concurrency-programming).

How can I implement such a design? I don't see any sub thread pool which can be created. Neither do I want to instantiate a thread pool for every request as that would be catastrophic.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's the behavior you want when a request has, say, 6 tasks but is limited to 5 threads?  Wait until one of the first 5 tasks completes before queueing the 6th task?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. But say another request comes with 5 tasks, give it separate 5 threads from the global thread pool.
And after the two requests have been submitted, 10 threads from the global pool is occupied and 1 task is still in waiting (from the first request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving this could be creating your callable methods to work on a list of elements instead of single elements.

For example, if you want to delete x items in a request, you can create lists of x/5 elements and pass this list to your callable function. This way, through code, you can ensure that at most only 5 threads will be utilized per request. You'll have to handle the exception scenarios with care though. (for e.g. you can return a Map of elementID to result enum, where result could be success, retryable excepiton or non retryable exception.)

This approach may vary depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: These are the two interpretations I understood from your answer:
So if I get 20 tasks in the first request, I divide it into a list of 4 items. [1-5,6-10,11-15,16-20] and submit 1-5 as one job (thread). What happens to the other 15?
Or I submit all 4 groups of tasks to 4 threads? First of all if I have more than 5*5 tasks (say 30) how do I handle it? Secondly in my usecase I want one task per thread. So when I submit one group to a thread, I have to again parallelize which will lead unnecessary overhead plus will violate my first condition that one request can only have 5 threads at a time.

Comment: If you have 20 requests, you'll create 5 lists of 4 elements each and process these 4 elements serially in the method. If you have 50 requests you'll create 5 lists of 10 elements each and process the 10 elements serially. What you are doing here is ensuring that you split your task into something that can be broken down to 5 smaller tasks that can run in parallel.

Comment: The approach sounds good. The only problem I see is that I am blocking one thread to orchestrate the list iteration. And it'll be a heavy task because it'll submit 4 jobs wait for them to finish then again submit 4 jobs and so on.
If I could use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor I can submit all of the jobs in a queue and retrieve that thread. I am looking for a solution where I could submit the job in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this would be to create a class that would throttle the tasks.  Each request would create a throttle and submit all its tasks to the throttle; the throttle would submit the first 5 (say) tasks to the Executor and put the others on a list.  As submitted tasks were completed, additional tasks could be submitted.

To determine when tasks were completed, the throttle could either poll the submitted tasks periodically, checking the Futures' isDone() method to see if they were done, or it could block on one Future's get() method until it was done and check on the other pending futures at that point, or if you wanted to get sophisticated, the request thread could wait() on the throttle and the tasks could be set up to notify() the throttle on completion so the request thread would then wake up and and check for completed tasks.